# AppEngine - JPA - simple OneToMany and ManyToOne relation does not work

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a simple relation:

- a category class, which contains zero to n questions
- a question class, which belongs to a category

I'm just trying to set the relations and creating a category and afterwards list this category and I always get a `503 Service Unavailable` error with empty message...

```
"domain": "global",
"reason": "backendError",
"message": ""
```

My classes look like the following:

**Category:**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
private String key;

private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

**Question:**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
private String key;

private String question;

@ManyToOne
private Category category;
```

Without the relations, I've no problem to insert categories and list them, but if I add the relation, it always fails... I tried already so many possibilities and it always fails to list the categories after I've inserted one...

Without the relations and with using a `fkCategory` string field instead of the `category`field for each question, I can get everything working, but that isn't efficient as far as I know, because in this "manual" way, the `fkCategory` field would not be indexed, am I right?

Comment: Are you using default App Engine DataStore (NoSQL schemaless object datastore)?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to use this. What exactly do you mean? If I checked an option somewhere in my google settings? Is there one? I do not use any custom settings...

Answer (score 0):

1. Insertion should work fine for category and question relation.
2. I think issue is with listing.

   - With datastore you can't use join query as this is not normal RDMS, check the section "comparison with traditional database" at  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/
   - You can check this by getting all Category list (do not touch questions relation on category object)
   - For question set category relation with FetchType.Lazy and list all questions ( do not touch category relation)
3. Check entire post at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/VMg9xiQv1jM